# 1/4 wavelength case in transmission lines

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line

I have studied that in transmission lines, if λ is the wavelength of the signal and L is the length of the conductor, then at L=λ/4 the transmission line act as an open circuit.

So if we are transmitting 1 GHz signal ( λ = 30cm ) through a conductor of length 7.5 cm, will there not be any output at the end?

Is this the reason why we use waveguides at microwave frequencies?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a few criteria for your statement, and that's getting you in trouble. Specifically, you don't say what's at the other end of that λ/4 transmission line, and that's a big part of the answer.

First, let me fill in some detail to your statement to make it fully qualified:

> ... at L=λ/4 the transmission line acts as an open circuit ***when the end of the transmission line is shorted (0 Ω).***

In this case, you aren't really concerned about there not being any power output at the end of the transmission line because you don't have it connected to anything, it's just a stub. You could definitely use a transmission line that is λ/4 for real power transmission.

The more general statement of your special case is that at λ/4, you have an impedance transformation that can be simplified to the following equation:

\$ \dfrac{Z_{IN}}{Z_0}=\dfrac{Z_0}{Z_{L}}\$

Waveguides are used at microwave frequencies because they have better power handling capability and lower loss than coaxial cable rated for the same frequencies.